# Slow performance on DOM manipulation in Internet Explorer when :first-of-type selector is present

Tags: javascript, performance, css, internet-explorer, dom

I've noticed that the time needed for the insertion of many DIVs into the DOM is heavily impacted if the CSS contains a selector like

```
tr:first-of-type
```

although the selector doesn't even match the elements to insert.
This only happens in Internet Explorer (I've tested IE9, IE10, IE11). I've also tried several ways to insert the elements to the DOM but without any success.

Measured values for inserting 10000 divs (using http://jsfiddle.net/3dqprd2s/):

- Chrome (without tr:first-of-type): 0.01s
- Chrome (with tr:first-of-type): 0.01s
- IE9 (without tr:first-of-type): 0.03s
- IE9 (with tr:first-of-type): **1.28s**

Am I missing something? Does anybody know a way to avoid this performance penalty?

Comment: Tried to rewrite your fiddle to use DOM methods to create the elements and put them into a DocumentFragment first – but that did not improve matters in IE either. I guess it’s just one of those IE bugs that you’ll have to live with …

Comment: Very interesting indeed. write `innerHTML` at once should be the fastest way to do that.